# I want to find fields from nested array in mongo document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am not able to select below fields from the document in mongodb

```
db.InsuranceRecords.find({$and:[{status: "BOOKED"}, {"products.status":"BOOKED"} ]})

db.InsuranceRecords.aggregate(
    {$match:{$and:[{status: "BOOKED"}, {"products.status":"BOOKED"} ]}},
    {$project:{        
        "tripId":1,
        "products": {$filter: {
            input: '$products',
            as: 'i',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$i.status', "BOOKED"]}
        }}
    }} )
```

Fields to select

```
    "tripId":1,
    "products[].internalName":1
    "products[].benefits[].internalName":1
    "products[].benefits[].cost[].amount":1
    "products[].benefits[].cost[].currencyCode":1
```

From the products array, there will be only 1 element having `products.status = booked`. However I want to read internal name of each benefit and their amount and currencyCode.

Comment: Could you share an example object from the collection and your expected output?
From what I understand so far you could look at $unwind to unwind the array of products, and then $match again to select the product you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output required here is how the projection query will look like:

```
db.getCollection("InsuranceRecords").aggregate([
{ $match: { status: "BOOKED" } },
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0, tripId: 1, _products: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$products',
                as: 'product',
                cond: { $eq: ['$$product.status', "BOOKED"] }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        tripId: 1,
        products: {
            $map: {
                "input": "$_products",
                "as": "prod",
                "in": {
                    "internalName": "$$prod.internalName",
                    "benefits": 
                        {
                            $map: {
                                "input": "$$prod.benefits",
                                "as": "benefit",
                                "in": {
                                    "internalName": "$$benefit.internalName",
                                    "cost":
                                        {
                                            $map:{
                                                "input":"$$benefit.cost",
                                                "as":"costs",
                                                "in":{
                                                    "amount":"$$costs.amount",
                                                    "currencyCode":"$$costs.currencyCode"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{ $sort: { tripId: 1 } }
])
```

Which will produce an output as:

```
/* 1 */
{
"tripId" : 1,
"products" : [
    {
        "internalName" : "Product7",
        "benefits" : [
            {
                "internalName" : "BenefitName13",
                "cost" : [
                    {
                        "amount" : "100",
                        "currencyCode" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "amount" : "200",
                        "currencyCode" : 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "internalName" : "BenefitName14",
                "cost" : [
                    {
                        "amount" : "300",
                        "currencyCode" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "amount" : "400",
                        "currencyCode" : 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
},
/* 2 */
{
"tripId" : 3,
"products" : [
    {
        "internalName" : "Product3",
        "benefits" : [
            {
                "internalName" : "BenefitName5",
                "cost" : [
                    {
                        "amount" : "100",
                        "currencyCode" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "amount" : "200",
                        "currencyCode" : 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "internalName" : "BenefitName6",
                "cost" : [
                    {
                        "amount" : "300",
                        "currencyCode" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "amount" : "400",
                        "currencyCode" : 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

> Explanation

The above query works in such a way:

- First, grab all the records from the `InsuranceRecords` collection where the head document has `status==" BOOKED"`.
- Then project the output with `products` filtered having `status==" BOOKED"`(*reason for not using that `products.status:"BOOKED"` in the `$match` as it will create an `and` condition where both the head-document and all the products have `status==" BOOKED"` and not a single entity in an array. So used filter to get the products instead.*) into `_products`.
- Again projected the above result to $map the required fields from the `_products` into `products`.
- Then sorted the result based on the `tripId`.

Sample json used to produce the above result:

```js
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d07685b964f7400e4de0382"),
 "name" : "Item1",
 "status" : "BOOKED",
 "products" : [
  {
   "status" : "Available",
   "internalName" : "Product1",
   "Name" : "ProductName1",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp1",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName1",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp2",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName2",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "status" : "Available",
   "internalName" : "Product2",
   "Name" : "ProductName2",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp3",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName3",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp4",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName4",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "status" : "BOOKED",
   "internalName" : "Product3",
   "Name" : "ProductName3",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp5",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName5",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp6",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName6",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "tripId" : 3
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d07682c964f7400e4de0381"),
 "name" : "Item2",
 "status" : "Available",
 "products" : [
  {
   "status" : "BOOKED",
   "internalName" : "Product4",
   "Name" : "ProdcutName4",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp7",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName7",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp8",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName8",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "status" : "BOOKED",
   "internalName" : "Product5",
   "Name" : "ProductName5",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp9",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName9",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp10",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName10",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "status" : "Available",
   "internalName" : "Product6",
   "Name" : "ProductName6",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp11",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName11",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp12",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName12",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "tripId" : 2
},

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d0767d6964f7400e4de0380"),
 "name" : "Item3",
 "status" : "BOOKED",
 "products" : [
  {
   "status" : "BOOKED",
   "internalName" : "Product7",
   "Name" : "ProductName7",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp13",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName13",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp14",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName14",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "status" : "Available",
   "internalName" : "Product8",
   "Name" : "ProductName8",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp15",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName15",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp16",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName16",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "status" : "Available",
   "internalName" : "Product9",
   "Name" : "ProductName9",
   "benefits" : [
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp17",
     "internalName" : "BenefitName17",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "100",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "200",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "someProp" : "BenefitProp18",
     "internalName" : "BenefitProp18",
     "cost" : [
      {
       "amount" : "300",
       "isUsed":0,
       "currencyCode" : 1
      },
      {
       "amount" : "400",
       "isUsed":1,
       "currencyCode" : 2
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "tripId" : 1
}
```

**Note:**

- There can be other approaches(*even better*) to filter the output(*ex: cursors*).
- As the sample data was not provided with the question i have populated my own to reproduce the data and required output.